# Toggle child menu in sidebar navigation nav-tabs bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was working on sidebar navigation(using bootstrap). But I got stuck here. I am not able to toggle the child menu . All I need to hide the child menu when I clicked on the top menu such as Main,Next Section and Third Section. For eg when I click on the Main menu it has to hide all the  child dashboard and click on Next section menu has to hide all sample section .

Any help highly appreciable

This is  the structure

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
        <li class="nav-header">Main</li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Dashboard</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Next Section</li>
        <li><a href='#'>Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Sample Section</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">Third Section</li>
        <li><a href='#'>Third Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Third Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Third Sample Section</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Third Sample Section</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.nextUntil()` like this..

```
$('.nav-header').click(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil('.nav-header').toggle(200);
});
```

Demo: **http://bootply.com/67126**

Comment: I'm just too slow today :P

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.nav-header').click(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('li.nav-header').toggle();
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/QmRVm/1/)